# " (Quotes) are getting converted into "&quot;" in Jboss logs

Tags: json, encoding, jboss, jboss-logging

I am facing an issue in which I am returning JSON string as AJAX Response. I have logging framework in-between which makes use of "periodic-rotating-file-handler" for logging the messages.
One of the user message which is getting logged is JSON String which doesn't come in correct format and **" (Quotes) are getting converted into "&quot"** in the Log file